# PHP, is_array() generating an "Undefined property: stdClass::$crit " error

Tags: php, arrays

`is_array($src2->crit)` is generating an "Undefined property: stdClass::$crit" error.

The line throwing the error is:
`if(is_array($src2->crit) && count($src->crit) > 0){`

`$src2->crit` is initialized here.

```
$src2->crit = array();
 $src2->crit[0] = new dataSet();
 $src2->crit[0]->tblName = $tbl2;
 $src2->crit[0]->colName = "ID";
 $src2->crit[0]->val = $elm->editID;
```

When testing `$src2->crit` with this code.

```
print("\$src->crit is a ".$src->crit."<br />");
print_r($src->crit); print("<br />");
```

This is returned.

```
$src2->crit is a Array
Array ( [0] => dataSet Object ( [tblName] => sExam [colName] => ID [val] => 10 ) )
```

What am I not seeing/understanding correctly? If `print("\$src2->crit is a ".$src->crit."<br />")` returns that it is an array then why is `is_array($src2->$crit)` generating an error?

Comment: I am confused, you are saying $elm->crit one place and $src->crit in another...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't reproduce:

```
<?php
$src2 = new stdClass();
$src2->crit = array();
$src2->crit[0] = new stdClass();
$src2->crit[0]->tblName = "whatever";
$src2->crit[0]->colName = "ID";
$src2->crit[0]->val = "value";
var_dump(is_array($src2->crit));
```

[gives](http://codepad.viper-7.com/sKUyF4) `bool(true)`.

Comment: I'll check to see if something else is throwing it off

Answer (score 0):

It appears your biggest issue (according to the info you posted in the question) is that you refencing a different varaible name?

```
$elm->crit
$src->crit
```

Comment: elm is the class which is being assigned to the src variable.

Comment: We will need more code posted then, what you have posted doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

`print("\$src2->crit is a ".$src->crit."<br />")`

`is_array($src2->$crit)`

One of these things is not like the other!

One's referencing the `crit` property of the `$src2` object.

The other is referencing the `$crit` property, meaning the value of the variable `$crit` is evaluated to a string, then that string value is used as the property name.

What's `$crit` defined as?  I'll bet it's not the string `'crit'`!